# Get previous rows value based on date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to the SQL world so this may be basic but I am trying to get the previous rows (multiple) value based on a a given time range.

I have a database table (bookmark) which captures food eaten and would like to assess all previous rows within a given time period to understand if the food item consumed has caused an allergy.

So for e.g. when I run the following query: -

```
SELECT food_word_1, date, lag(food_word_1,1) OVER (ORDER BY date) as maybe_this FROM bookmark WHERE mood = 'allergies'
```

The result is the following:-

```
 food_word_1 |            date            | maybe_this 
-------------+----------------------------+------------
 bread       | 2018-11-14 09:30:54.272882 | 
 coffee      | 2018-11-15 12:49:46.119737 | bread
 beef        | 2018-11-15 20:22:51.924697 | coffee
 pasta       | 2018-11-15 20:23:21.579621 | beef
 cereal bar  | 2018-11-16 07:53:22.098064 | pasta
 red wine    | 2018-11-16 09:03:29.589634 | cereal bar
 nuts        | 2018-11-20 07:43:17.910149 | red wine
 duck        | 2018-11-21 12:38:31.463169 | nuts
 cereal bar  | 2018-11-25 09:09:54.187615 | duck
 salad       | 2018-12-12 21:53:47.258954 | cereal bar
```

So 'bread' was eaten/inputted (maybe_this) 1 row prior to 'coffee' (Food_word_1).

I am using the Lag Function here but I am not sure this is the right way to go but it shows approximately what I am trying to achieve, but rather than defining the exact number of previous rows to assess (so 1 in this case using the Lag Function), I wish to select a time period of 36 Hours.

Any help appreciated,

md

Comment: Can you share you what your desired results would be give this sample data? Perhaps this can be solved with a self join.

Comment: Can you not add an AND clause to WHERE to get all rows before a given date/time ? e.g. `AND date < '2018-11-15 20:22:51.924697'` That would give you all the rows before that date.

Comment: So if there are previous records within the last 36 hours, you want to display the latest one. What if there are no records with the last 36 hours ?

Comment: @JNevill Sorry if I was not clear. The desired result would be to assess the previous 36 hours of inputted data prior to the column 'mood' having 'allergies' inputted. The goal is to understand whenever I am having allergies, to correspond this to food I have eaten recently

Comment: @Dugggie I tried this originally (remember I am a real novice here) and I could not work out how to take the date from the row which also had 'allergies' listed in the 'mood' column, and use this as the reference point to calculate 36 hours prior to this. So that's what sent me down the Windows Function Lag path. If I could somehow build a query where it finds 'allergies' listed in the 'mood' column, and then take and present the 'food_word_1' from the previous rows in the 36 hr period, this would be perfect

Comment: @GMB If there are no food_words captured in the 36hr prior period, I would like to simply return a "sorry, no food items were registered in this period' message.

Comment: Hi @ micdoher, I can't see a mood column in your example so not sure what is in there. You need to use a dateadd type function, which will depend on which type of SQL you are using. The answer by @JohnHC should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all of them as a big list using stringagg after self left joining:

```
select t1.food_word_1 , t1.date, 
       string_agg(t2.food_word_1,',') as also_maybe -- make the list
from MyTable t1
left join MyTable t2
  on t2.date >= t1.date - (36 * interval '1 hour') -- the previous 36 hours
  and t1.food_word_1 <> t2.food_word_1 -- let's ignore the food we've already listed in column 1
  and t2.mood = 'allergies' -- limit the results for the list
where t1.mood = 'allergies' -- limit the results for each group
group by t1.food_word_1, t1.date
```

Comment: Thank you John as I think you may have moved me in the right direction as seem to be getting calculated results but have noticed there are too many as there is no WHERE statement in there to define the results need to be only when a column names 'mood' = 'allergies'. I have played around and can't seem to insert it without breaking the code. Do you know how to add this logic please?

Comment: Many thanks again here @JohnHC as this is nearly it!!! One last tweak I have realized now I was looking for is that this query seems assess everything in the last 36hrs (which is what I originally asked for), but is it easy to change this to assess inputs approximately 36hrs previous to an 'allergies' but only consider the food_word_1 closes to that time rather than everything in-between?